# Splitting ambiguous [tiger] tag

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retag-request, tag-disambiguation

First of all, I realize how low-priority this question is, the concerned tag representing 27 questions, but it is still necessary to raise this issue:

As far as I knew, The [tiger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tiger) tag represented the language featured by Andrew Appel, in his book "Modern Compiler Implementation".

However, after proposing a tag definition, I saw a few of those questions targeted 
TIGER (`Topologically Integrated Geographic Encoding and Referencing`) products from the US census bureau. Those files are mostly databases and shapefiles, which could be grouped under a [tiger-census](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tiger-census) tag, leaving [tiger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tiger) for the language.

**Edit**:

So I hadn't noticed but this tag also dragged questions about Mac OSX 10.4 Tiger, so while we're at it let's also add the tag [osx-tiger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/osx-tiger) to the list!

Comment: I've retagged all questions related to OS X with [tag:osx-tiger]. I hope there will be no more, because OS X Tiger is very old.

Comment: @VadimKotov:  Do you think we (the community) could've had a moment to sit down and digest those questions?  Tiger *is* very old, and so were those questions.  It would have been nice to go through them and see which ones weren't worth editing and would've been concise to delete.

Comment: @Makoto there were like 10 of them. You can clean-up them, they were put into 38 questions tagged with [tag:osx-tiger]

Comment: Just take a look at recently active questions here -- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/osx-tiger?sort=active&pageSize=50